# aws ecs execute-command failed because was not enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, execute

I am running `aws ecs execute-command --cluster UltimaF --task 838d773b17954bcfbbacf343fb4fea70 --container ultima --interactive --command "/bin/sh"`

Getting back: `An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the ExecuteCommand operation: The execute command failed because execute command was not enabled when the task was run or the execute command agent isn’t running. Wait and try again or run a new task with execute command enabled and try again.`

I have ensured that:

1. The task is running.
2. `aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster UltimaF --tasks 838d773b17954bcfbbacf343fb4fea70` returns `"enableExecuteCommand": true`
3. Task role has the following permissions attached:

   - `ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel`
   - `ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel`
   - `ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel`
   - `ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel`

I am running on Windows, aws-cli/2.8.2

**UPDATE**:
after running [ecs exec checker](https://github.com/aws-containers/amazon-ecs-exec-checker) I have two yellow items and one red:

```
    ----------
      Managed Agent Status
    ----------
         1. STOPPED (Reason: null) for "ultima" - LastStartedAt: null
    ----------
      Init Process Enabled (first-run-task-definition:12)
    ----------
         1. Disabled - "ultima"
```

**UPDATE** two:

[This](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/361) issue suggests
`ecs:clustername_taskid_containerruntimeid` but for me it returns an error: `An error occurred (TargetNotConnected) when calling the StartSession operation: ecs:UltimaF_838d773b17954bcfbbacf343fb4fea70_838d773b17954bcfbbacf343fb4fea70-2587323273 is not connected.`

Question: How do I connect?

Comment: Did you go through all the requirement here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/ecs-exec.html

Comment: 1) I am not using VS Code here. 2) the link you sent really just mentions Enable Command Execution. I did that.

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html But both links mention other things like the required IAM role permissions on the ECS task.

Comment: Thank you! The link does mention managed agent needs to be running but doesn't say anything about what to do if it is Stopped and why it is.

Comment: Did you verify it has the correct IAM permissions needed to connect to the SSM service?

Comment: Yes indeed. see point 3.

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov did you get this working? I have same issues, the 
"enableExecuteCommand": true  but still the managedAgent is STOPPED with no status. :(

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that in your task definition's structure/JSON "*enableExecuteCommand*" is set to true.

`aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster <CLUSTER> --tasks <TASK_ARN>`

Comment: This itself is the problem: enableExecuteCommand is set to true in the service, but it still false in the task

Comment: `aws ecs update-service --cluster your-cluster-name --service your-service-name --force-new-deployment`

Comment: OR Ensure that the IAM role associated with your EC2 instances has the necessary permissions to use the ECS Exec feature. It should have the ecs:ExecuteCommand permission.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before and after running the execute-command  it's still the same so I removed the task under service and the new container got access with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. https://dev.to/aws-builders/how-to-run-a-shell-on-ecs-fargate-containers-eo1
2. `aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster-name> --service <service-name> --force-new-deployment --enable-execute-command`.

This will enable it

Answer (score 0):

What was happening in my case, was that the container's process was actually failing (std error -1). Once I fixed internal error of the process, I was able to run the task